# Strange behavior of extended C++ function

Tags: python, c++, extending

I'm writing Python wrapper for C++ function `repeating_count::count(string str)`. The algorithm of this function isn't important, but it always return `int`.
My wrapper gets `list[str]` as input and returns `list[int]`. The code of my wrapper is below:

```
PyObject* count_rep_list(PyObject *mod, PyObject *args){
    PyObject* inputList = PyList_GetItem(args, 0);
    PyObject* outputList = PyList_New(0);
    cout << PyList_Size(inputList);
    char* str;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < PyList_Size(inputList); ++i){
        PyObject* list_item = PyList_GetItem(inputList, i);
        if(!PyArg_Parse(list_item, "s", &str)){
            return NULL;
        }
        PyList_Append(outputList, PyLong_FromSize_t(repeating_count::count(string(str))));
    }
    return outputList;
}
```

Then I made a python module with this function:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_repeating_count() {
    static PyMethodDef ModuleMethods[] = {
            {"count_rep_list", count_rep_list, METH_VARARGS, "counting repeatings for list of strings"},
            { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
    };
    static PyModuleDef ModuleDef = {
            PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
            "repeating_count",
            "counting repeatings",
            -1, ModuleMethods,
            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    };
    PyObject * module = PyModule_Create(&ModuleDef);
    return module;
}
```

I successfully compiled and linked this module in `.so` file. But when I want to call the function from Python 3, I catch

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

**So, what I'm doing wrong?**

The fragment of Python code for calling `count()`:

```
from repeating_count import *
print(count_rep_list(["sdfsf", "sf", "sdfvgsdgsd"]))
```

Comment: str is an unitialized pointer which you are passing to PyArg_Parse

Comment: @KennyOstrom, thanks a lot. I've corrected the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. There was simply an error in code.

I had to use `PyTuble_GetItem(args, 0)` instead of `PyList_GetItem(args, 0)` beacuse `args` is a tuple.